# Best practice for buildscript tag in build.gradle of library projects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

I'm wondering what is the best / intended way of defining build script repositories and dependencies for Android library projects.

Out in the wild (like Github) most of the repos define the following in there build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
} }
```

But if I create a library project in Android Studio this buildscript block does not get created, as it is already in the root build.gradle file, and therefore not necessary (I assume).

So what is the proper way, only defining it once in the root build.gradle or for each library project (which also means updating the version number for each library in case of new plugin versions). Or does it depend whether I want to release the library independently from my main application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're developing a library, there isn't really a top-level **build.gradle**: that top level applies to all modules in a multimodule project, but a library is best implemented as a standalone single module.

Probably the best practice would be to have a single **build.gradle** file for your library module, and include a `buildscript` block in it with the repository and Android plugin Gradle version. That way it stands alone better, and it's not implicitly dependent on being in a project that has a top-level build.gradle file.

There's a huge caveat which kind of renders a lot of this moot, however -- if you include this module, with its own `buildscript` block, in a project that has a top-level **build.gradle** with a competing `buildscript` block, the top-level build file will win and it will ignore the block in your module.

This probably isn't much of a problem, but if your module relied on a specific version of the Android Gradle plugin, for example, and it was in a project that used a different version of the plugin, then your module would lose and it could run into problems. Another way of saying it is that it can only use one version of a plugin for all of the modules in a single build, and I believe the first one to specify it sets it for everyone.

In practice, this is only likely to be an issue if you rely on some feature specific to a later-than-1.0 version of the Android Gradle plugin, and it's included in a project that uses 1.0.

There are some subtleties here that I'll mention but won't answer (and I apologize for answering your question with more questions) -- if anyone else knows for sure, please answer yourself, or edit my answer, or mention it in the comments:

- What if your `buildscript` block adds new plugins to the classpath? Do they get added or are they ignored?
- What if your `buildscript` block adds new repositories to the search path? Will they get picked up?

Comment: I flipped the bit to make this answer community wiki, so please feel free to edit it. It didn't feel right to get the points for upvotes when it asks more questions than it answers.

Comment: Even though you opened some other (quite good) questions you answered my one. Thanks. So from my point of view it makes no sense to include the buildscript block to a library that is not intended to stand alone as its buildscript block gets ignored anyways